# Facebook wall post link contains some extra Parameters

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using this code for writing to my facebook wall

```
$AccessToken       = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
    $attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $AccessToken,
    'message' => "$Msg",
    'name' => 'some content',
    'link' => $link,
    'picture' => "$ShareImage",
    'description' => '',
    'caption'=>'',
    'properties' => array (
                              'Send one to a friend now:' => array  (
                                        'text' => 'Facebook App ',
                                        'href' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/appname/'
                                       ),
                              'Become a fan:' => array  (
                                        'text' => 'Page Name',
                                        'href' => 'http://www.Facebook.com/page/'
                                       )
);
```

It is working fine.But the problem is from the image the link is containing some extra parameter eg: `www.mysite.com?id=12&ref=nf`
But from the text the link showing the current link.Is their any way to remove the content `ref=nf` from the link that is pointing from the image

Comment: why do u wana remove it, its jus a reference facebook is adding, that tells u the link is coming from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to remove those *extra* parameters. `ref` is always added by Facebook to your links so you'll be able to track there from user visited it.

**nf** indicating user came from link he saw in **News Feed**

Comment: You may also want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806237/what-does-ref-ts-mean-in-a-facebook-application-url